# How long for a question to come off "hold" after the requested edit has been done?

Tags: support

The original formulation of this question:

[Is there any known context in which a simple concatenation operator is defined so as to produce "abbc" from (a,b,c), "abbccd" from (a,b,c,d) etc?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2546260/is-there-any-known-context-in-which-a-simple-concatenation-operator-is-defined-s)

was put on hold until an edit was done for clarification.

I reformulated the question to clarify it but the question is still on hold.

How long does it generally take for a question to come off "hold" once a requested edit has been done?

I'm not complaining here - please believe me when I say that.  Just want to know whether I should simply delete the question, since it hasn't come off hold.

Comment: Unfortunately, you seemed to believe the question "was put on hold until an edit was done for clarification."  That's only part of the story.  An edit (first edit of post after it was put on hold) sends the question to the review queue, and specifically, the "re-open queue".  Reopening requires enough users to agree that the question is reopened, (i.e. 5 users voting to reopen a question is needed).  Perhaps I can summarize: editing/improving a post does not guarantee that it is then taken off-hold.

Comment: @amWhy - thanks for taking the time to respond.  So I should just be patient and wait?  Also, if the decision is to NOT reopen, is the question deleted, or does it stay available "read-only".

Comment: The review in the reopen queue was [completed](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/915948) yesterday. No one voted to reopen.

Comment: Well, currently there are no positive score on the answers, and the last I looked, your question had a score of 0, too.  In ~8-9 days, if that status continues, there is an auto-deletion script for such questions.  Since there are no upvoted answers, you are free to delete the question.

Comment: OK - thanks . . .

Comment: @amWhy - I just tried to delete and the system told me that I can't delete because too many people put too much effort into their answers - so I guess I will just wait for the auto-delete .... thanks again

Comment: @JohnMa - please see my last comment to amWhy re no permission to delete .... can you delete it for me ... ?

Comment: @DavidHalitsky I must have been mistaken re the ability of an asker to delete a post with no upvoted answers, but answers nonetheless.  So it may just be a matter of letting the auto delete take care of it.  Only mods can delete, unilaterally, another's question, unless the question has 3 or more downvotes, in which case, there must be three experienced users that vote to delete.  But that changes as a question ages.  I do very much appreciate your question, your sincerity, and your effort to improve the question.

Comment: @amWhy - thanks for the kind words - and thank you also  for being responsive here "above and beyond the call of duty" . ..

Comment: @amWhy - now I'm REALLY puzzled - because Gerry Myerson was able to add a comment a few minutes ago, and I was able to respond.  So what exactly does "on-hold" mean - that it can't be "answered" officially?

Comment: David Ahhh, yes, when a question is on hold, it means no further *answers* are allowed (*answers* meaning no one can post a new answer in an answer field).   But others can still comment, and you can comment too.  And you can edit. And answerers can edit their answers. People can still vote on the question and/or answers (those present prior to being put on hold).  Bottom line: being put on hold simply prohibits new answers (in answer fields).

Comment: @amWhy - thanks for the clarification - I'm kinda sorry now that the auto-delete will kick-in in a week or so, because Gerry's observation might be really useful, inasmuch as our applied context is VERY similar to ones in which the Trapezoidal Rule is invoked. And therefore, a little bit of history will disappear when the auto-delete fires . . .

Comment: Well, who knows what will happen in response to this post here on meta;  it may garner further interest (but also possible additional criticism).  Be sure to take a screen-shot of the question and comments, and save it, just in case.

Comment: @amWhy - will do, thanks . . .